# Custom Mediator ClassNotFoundException TransactionSynchronization

Tags: spring, wso2, spring-jdbc, wso2-esb

I make a custom mediator class that used spring jdbc to access data from database. 
I make a jar from that class and deploy it in WSO2_HOME/repository/components/lib.
 After that I add the following jar to the same folder : 
spring-jdbc.jar,
 spring-tx.jar. 
But when I tried the custom mediator there is an error "ClassNotFoundException org\springframework\transaction\support\TransactionSynchronization". 
The problem is  I'm pretty sure that "TransactionSynchronization" class is available in the spring-tx.jar. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? :)

Comment: Can you start the server with -DosgiConsole and see if the "spring-tx.jar" is installed correctly? You can see the bundle state using "ss spring-tx" at osgi console.

Comment: @Lahiru Hi thanks for your responds..I tried the ss spring_tx command and the result said it is "ACTIVE"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason may be there are two packages in your class path which has the same 'TransactionSynchronization' class. Can you try the below.

1. What do you have in your WSO2_HOME/repository/components/dropins directory? Delete all jars inside dropins and restart the server and recheck for the issue.
2. If the error is still there try deleting spring-tx.jar from WSO2_HOME/repository/components/lib & WSO2_HOME/repository/components/dropins. Then restat the server. Then check whether you are getting the same error or different error?

Comment: Thanks, I know what the problem now, the problem is the package in spring-jdbc.jar and spring-tx.jar. The package name is similiar, so when the class use the "org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.class" it search from the spring-jdbc.jar. Solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same behavior.  I have a custom spring mediator that calls out to a database for role based authNZ.  I am running esb v 4.7.0.

I downloaded spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar from the maven repository and copied it to /usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/components/lib in my environment, then restarted the ESB.  When I issue requests to my proxy service, the same class not found exception occurs.

I was examining jar contents today and when I checked the spring-tx jar in /usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/components/lib, the class in present:

```
jar tf spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar | grep TransactionSynchronization
org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.class
```

When I do the same in /usr/local/wso2/wso2esb-4.7.0/repository/components/dropins after restart of the esb, the class is not present:

```
jar tf ../dropins/spring_tx_3.1.0.RELEASE_1.0.0.jar 
spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/p2.inf
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Notice that the spring-tx jar is not included in the OSGi bundle after restart of Synapse.

I will investigate further tomorrow, including building an OSGi bundle that contains the Spring dependencies I need via Eclipse

Comment: just like Mr.lakmali-erandi said, please check your lib folder, maybe there is a jar that contain the same package with the spring-tx.jar.

Comment: Mari, 

What did you end up doing to solve the class loading issue?

Comment: Hi Juan, I solved this by editing my jar. In my case I have 2 jar (spring-jdbc.jar and spring-tx.jar), So I joined all the class in both jar in one jar than  deployed that one jar in the lib folder. I don't know if there is a better solution for this, but at least this can solved my problem :)

Comment: I was finally able to solve my issue by downloading the pre-bundled osgi jars for spring-jdbc and spring-tx from http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/ and copying them to dropins.  Before, I was copying the non osgi bundled Spring jars to the lib directory and letting carbon convert for me.  I can't believe I didn't look for the osgi versions of the jars that I needed before.

Apparently the conversion gave both the jdbc and tx bundles the same values for id and bundle path.
ss | grep spring
was a lifesaver after restarting 4.6.0 esb in osgi console mode.